# Limit to single decimal point and Update all the integer scores to have ".0" with exception of the score of 10 and 0

Tags: javascript

Limit to singal decimal point and Update all the integer scores to have `.0` with exception of the score of `10` and `0`.

FOR Example :

```
0.972 shall be 0.9
2.83 - 2.8
```

All the integer scores should be updated as

```
0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10
```

I have taken care of single digit after decimal with regular expression

```
parseFloat(pillarScore.match(/^-?\d*(?:\.\d{0,1})?/)[0]);
```

But how to get that updated integer part. Currently it returns it as 1,2,3 etc .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format your number with particular character length after point and [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator to detect if a number is divisible by 10.

```js
function formatNumber(n) {
  return n % 10 ? (parseInt(n * 10) / 10).toFixed(1) : n;
}

console.log(formatNumber(0));
console.log(formatNumber(1));
console.log(formatNumber(3));
console.log(formatNumber(10));
console.log(formatNumber(0.972));
```